How do I layer click through on a form?
I'm working on an application that allows me to have a photo I can drag around the screen while the form is invisible and click-through; the photo itself is unfortunately also click-through with my current code.
I've been looking all over and everything tells me to use SetWindowLong() when making a form click-through and see through, however I can't find anything on layering what I want to click-through and what I don't.
This is the current code I'm using;
uint ex_style = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL.ExStyle);  
SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL.ExStyle, ex_style | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
 
ex_style = GetWindowLong(button1.Handle, GWL.ExStyle);
SetWindowLong(button1.Handle, GWL.ExStyle, ex_style & 0 & 0);
    
public const uint WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x00080000;
public const uint WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;
public enum GWL
{
    ExStyle = -20
}
    
public enum WS_EX
{
    Transparent = 0x20,
    Layered = 0x80000
}
    
public enum LWA
{
    ColorKey = 0x1,
    Alpha = 0x2
}
    
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern uint GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, GWL nIndex);
    
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern uint SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, GWL nIndex, uint dwNewLong);

It effectively makes the window click-through however it does not allow me to click the button that is on the form...
